# Confusion about Object.GetType().Name

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace somens
{
    class GettingTypeName
    {
        static void MethodUsingVar()
        {
            var someInt = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("someInt is a : {0}", someInt.GetType().FullName);    
            Console.WriteLine("someInt is a : {0}", someInt.GetType().Name); //Why .Name?
        }   

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MethodUsingVar();
            Console.ReadLine();    
        }
    }
}

//Output
//someInt is a : System.Int32;
//someInt is a : Int32;
```

I understand the usage of `someInt.GetType().FullName`, since it "*Gets the fully qualified name of the type*,"(quote from Microsoft).

But I don't know why `someInt.GetType().Name` would give `Int32.` The `Name` property of the returned `Type` class "*gets the name of the current member.*" (Another quote from the same Microsoft page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx)

Since it is used for members' names of a particular type, how does the code output the correct type name (without namespace) instead? It just doesn't make sense.

Thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "Since it is used for members' names of a particular type" - no, it's used for the name of the type. The name of the System.Int32 type (without namespace) is Int32...

Comment: dosent make sense? full name gives fully qualified name of the type. then what would be the purpose of "Name"?

Comment: The compiler knows that the type of `var someInt` to be `int`. So, during runtime it is an `int`. So, its full name is `System.Int32` and `Name` is `Int32. What is this question about, actually?

Comment: I think your confusion is that you think `Name` should give name of variable `someInt`?

Comment: I have edited my questions, so it may be clearer. I don't understand the downvotes. Isn't it not a legitimate question? Visual Studio IntelliSense also use the hit "Gets the name of the current member".

Comment: @JohnSmithSr. Ok, just tell what result do you expect to be outputed?

Comment: @Yeldar I am not expecting any output, I am merely confused at the fact (based on Microsoft's own wording) that .Name property can't even be used here. I can live with that fact that using .Name would give me an unqualified name of the TYPE, and it bothers me that it does not do what the documentation(or intellisense) says it should do. I would really appreciate if is you could point our what step of my reasoning is incorrect instead of people giving me downvotes by looking at my post title.

Comment: If you ask a question that can't be understood, it's not helpful - hence downvotes. Now that you've clarified it, it's better.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet, sorry I didn't make myself clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Name property of the returned Type class "*gets the name of the current member.*"

This is what it says because it's the general description of [`MemberInfo.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx). It's not wrong, but not exactly clear. The type `System.Int32` is a member of `mscorlib`'s main module. You wouldn't ordinarily think of it as a member, but it does mean that it gets the name of the type.

Comment: @Thanks hvd, it does help clarify something. Now my question is how do you determine the CONTEXT of the .Name property? I thought it was the TYPE,(because it was following the TYPE)  hence my confusion. But how do you determine it should be mscorlib? It may be an unrelated question, but I really want to understand the reasoning behind this.  Is there some other thing we should consider when seeing a property following a type/object and a dot operator?  Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmithSr. You're asking for the `Name` property of `typeof(int)`. The name of what C# calls `int` is `Int32`. Therefore, you get `Int32`. The rest is just clarification on why the documentation reads the way it does. It's the type `System.Int32` inside a module inside `mscorlib.dll`, and all that can be found by inspecting other properties on `typeof(int)`, such as `typeof(int).Assembly`.

Answer (score 3):

The "member" here isn't your variable - it's a member of the namespace (or assembly, or module if you want). (It's unfortunate that the documentation is inherited from `MemberInfo` - if it said "the name of the type" it would be clearer.)

You're dealing with a `Type` - you'll get the same `Type` object whether you call `GetType()` or use `typeof(int)`. The type is the `Int32` type in the `System` namespace, so its full name is `System.Int32` and its name is `Int32`. The `Type` object has *no knowledge* of your variable.

Comment: I thought it was a third option: assemblies contain modules, modules contain types. The type is a member of the module.

Comment: @hvd: Possibly. Will add that as another option.

Answer (score -1):

.FullName - returns a name of an object's type including namespace and assembly description

.Name - returns object's type name only

Comment: It's not returning the names of *objects*, but of *types*.

Comment: Yep, stating that `.Name` returns the object's name is exactly the misconception OP has.

Comment: I actually understand it won't return the object's name.  My question was why it was a valid statement at all.